# Python twitterbot using node.js

Tags: python, node.js, twitter, plesk

Recently I followed a [tutorial](http://www.adamhammond.com/botguide/) to make a simple twitterbot, however I've stumbled on a problem when trying to actually deploy it. It posts fine if I start it via ssh, but I would like to run it as an application, so it could just post by itself on the timer I set it on...

I have my own virtual server (Ubuntu 16.04 running Plesk 17.8) to experiment on and I would prefer not having to use an external service to host the bot, but since Plesk dropped support for python on the current version I guess the only option would be to run it via node.js, right? I've set up a domain for the bot, as well as the application in Plesk, but the problem is I've foolishly thought I could just use the .py file I made with the tutorial... This not being the case, do I have to convert the script, or is there a way to execute the script through javascript (and have it stay running)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To be able to run a python script on a server you will to set up a [WSGI server](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html). You don't have to do it manually, you can also use any of the available web frameworks such as [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) (Flask will do for you as it's really simple and Tornado is asynchronous). You may have to rewrite your code a little for that purpose and also add some more necessary scripts for server to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I couldn't really figure out how to get the code I had to work with Flask, but you definitely put me in the right direction, managed to make it work using [a tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-twitterbot-with-python-3-and-the-tweepy-library) I found searching for Flask tutorials.